# necessary and sufficient condition about weak convergence on N (the set of natural numbers)

Tags: probability-theory, analysis, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

I would like to show that if all natural number $k$ satisfy that
$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu_{n}(\{k\})=\mu(\{k\})$, then $\{\mu_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges on  $\mu$ weakly, where $\{\mu_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, $\mu$ are probability measure(s)
on $\mathbb{N}$.

I know that all I have to do is to prove
$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \varphi(k)\mu_n(\{k\})=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \varphi(k)\mu(\{k\})$ for all bounded $\varphi$.

In order to show that $\lim$ and $\sum$ can be commuted, I tried to use Dominated Convergence Theorem and Fatou's Lemma, but neither worked out.

Are there any good idea? Thank you.

Comment: To prove the limit, you can just split $|\sum^\infty_k \mu_n \phi - \mu \phi |$ into 3 sums which all converge to 0, no need of general theorems since the series here all converge.

Comment: I have solved this problem! Thank you for your advice!